# I cannot start SQL Server browser

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, 64-bit

I can't start the `SQL Server browser` from `SQL Service Configuration Manager 2008` version. There are absolutely no options to start the service. It's disabled as image shown below. How should I start the service again?

[image: window]

Comment: If you choose Properties can you change the start mode to something other than disabled? e.g. automatic and then start it?

Comment: no its also not possible something like error 1058 appear

Answer (score 210):

If it is disabled, go to **Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services**, and look for the **SQL Server Agent**. Right-click, and select **Properties** From the **Startup Type** dropdown, change from **Disabled** to **Automatic**.

Comment: What should I if starting SQL Server Agent is also grayed out?

Comment: The question was regarding SQL Server _Browser_, not the Agent.

Comment: @EJMak The same process appears to work for the browser.

Comment: It is already "Automatic" for me, but I still have OP's problem.

Comment: @ChristoferOhlsson "Automatic" referes to the "Startup Type". Check the "Status" of the service, which should be "Running".

Comment: I did that from SQL Server Config Manager

Comment: @BenR make sure you are login with administrator user

Answer (score 24):

My approach was similar to @SoftwareFactor, but different, perhaps because I'm running a different OS, *Windows Server 2012*. These steps worked for me.

`Control Panel` > `System and Security` > `Administrative Tools` > `Services`,
right-click `SQL Server Browser` > `Properties` > `General tab`,
change `Startup` type to `Automatic`,
click `Apply` button,
then click `Start` button in `Service Status` area.

Answer (score 22):

Make sure that you run the SQL Server Configuration Manager snap-in as Administrator if UAC is enabled.  Then right click the service and then click properties, change the start mode to enabled, then start it.

Answer (score 17):

Clicking Properties, going to the Service tab and setting Start Mode to Automatic fixed the problem for me.  Now the Start item in the context menu is active again.

Comment: I get an error `The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled or because it has no enabled devices associated with it. [0x80070422]`

Answer (score 13):

go to Services, find SQL Server Browser, right click --> Properties --> General tab --> Startup Type --> select automatic . Then go back to configuration management, start it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm trying to setup rf online game to be played offline using MS SQL server 2019 and ended up with the same problem. The SQL Browser service won't start. Almost all answers in this post have been tried but the outcome is disappointing. I've got a weird idea to try start the SQL browser service manually and then change it to automatic after it runs. Luckily it works. So, just simply right click on **SQL Server Browser** ==> **Properties** ==>**Service**==>**Start Mode**==>**Manual**. After apply the changes right click on the SQL Server Browser again and start the service. After the service run change the start mode to automatic. Make sure the information provided on log on as: are correct.

Answer (score 2):

run > regedit > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > WOW6432Node > Microsoft > Microsoft SQL Server > 90 > SQL Browser > SsrpListener=0

Answer (score 1):

right click on SQL Server browser and properties, then Connection tab and chose open session with system account and not this account.
then apply and chose automatic and finally run the server.