# SQL Server Browser Service not present in SQL server configuration manager

Tags: sql-server

I am not able to connect to my (LocalDb)\v11.0 from OLAP Cube project while deploying because of the SQL Server Browser Service is not running.

I am getting error like

> "Error 4   The project could not be deployed to the '(LocalDb)\v11.0' server because of the following connectivity problems :  A connection cannot be made to redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running.  To verify or update the name of the target server, right-click on the project in Solution Explorer, select Project Properties, click on the Deployment tab, and then enter the name of the server.        0   0"

So I opened the SQL server configuration manager and tried to make the sql server browser service on but I am not able to find it in the configuration manager

Please suggest what should I do?

Comment: What is the exact version of your SQL Server installation. Run `SELECT @@VERSION;` on your target SQL Server database.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64)

Comment: This is very odd, maybe you can install it afterwards by running the setup once again ?

Comment: That is not the whole version. It should include whether it's standard edition, express edition, enterprise edition etc. Copy the whole string please.

Comment: @TT. Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3000.0 (X64) 
 Oct 19 2012 13:38:57 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Express Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

Comment: Did you browse through this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21375014/243373

Comment: Also this: https://serverfault.com/q/383177/250310

Comment: Yes, but I am not able to see the SQL Server Services I.e even not able to see the sql server instance

Comment: Actually on my local machine SQL server is not installed only SSMS is installed, thats why I am not able to see the SQL services in the SQL Configuration Manager.
And I am connecting the (LocalDb)\v11.0 through SSMS.

Thank you all for your comments.