# Error 50: local DB run time error occurred for SQL Server 2012 - 32bit window 7

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have installed local DB and SSMS for my project. When I tried to create database in `App_data` [for an ASP.NET MVC application], I get an error

> Error 50: local DB run time error occurred.

When I checked the services, it's showing only "SQL Server vss writer".

I think I'm missing other services that are required to connect to a database from an ASP.NET MVC application.

Could any one please suggest me from which link, I need to install these? I basically wanted to create a database for ASP.NET MVC 1st approach.. Any other way to resolve this local DB run time error? I need something free for my POC. Please help.

Comment: Does it say anything after local DB run time error occurred? It usually gives a better description right after that.

Comment: After this its saying : The specified LocalDB instance does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question here, you need to stat the other `open Run type-> services.msc` - under services -> **`sort by stopped`** you will see a bunch of stopped SQL services `Right click and start`

To begin - there are 4 issues that could be causing the ***common* LocalDb SqlExpress Sql Server connectivity errors** `SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred`, before you begin you *[need to rename the v11 or v12 to (localdb)\mssqllocaldb](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2014_0010.htm)*

- You dont have the [services running](http://[![w8KFa.gif](https://s23.postimg.org/xhz3281dn/w8_KFa.gif)](https://postimg.org/image/e04fma4fr/))
- You don't have the [firelwall ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogkmm.png) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774827/cant-connect-to-localhost-on-sql-server-express-2012-2016)
  configured
- Your install has and issue/corrupt (the steps below help give you a nice clean start)
- You did not [rename the V11 or 12 to mssqllocaldb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26248293/sql-network-interfaces-error-50-local-database-runtime-error-occurred-canno)

*I found that the simplest is to do the below - I have attached the pics and steps for help.*

First verify which instance you have installed, you can do this by **checking the registry** *and* **by running cmd**

1. `cmd> Sqllocaldb.exe i`
2. `cmd> Sqllocaldb.exe s "whicheverVersionYouWantFromListBefore"` 
   if this step fails, you can delete with option `d` cmd> Sqllocaldb.exe d "someDb"
3. `cmd> Sqllocaldb.exe c "createSomeNewDbIfyouWantDb"`
4. `cmd> Sqllocaldb.exe start "createSomeNewDbIfyouWantDb"`

[image: SqlLOCALDb_edited.png]