# Local server in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, installation, server

I've installed Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Studio today and now I'm trying to connect to server. As far as I know there should be default local server that would allow me to create a database in it. Unfortunately, my list of servers is empty and I cannot connect to anything. I've read tutorials and tried everything, even reinstalling all the Microsoft SQL Package. How can I fix this problem and find/create my local server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774827/cant-connect-to-localhost-on-sql-server-express-2012

Comment: Did you install **ONLY** the management studio?? That's **JUST** the management GUI - but **NOT** the actual database server! You need to install **both** the actual database engine / server, *and* the Management Studio ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've read that there might be a problem with connecting to database even if whole microsoft package gives me LocalDB. I had to install Visual Studio, then clicked View -> SQL Server Project Explorer. Right click at 'SQL Server', I added new database and then entered its name. Now I can connect with my own server by typing '(localdb)\v11.0' in management studio.