# New user cannot log-in (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-connection, ssms

I created a SQL user "myUser" within the Security > Logins section in SSMS. I created it as "SQL Server Auth" and granted all permissions. This user still cannot sign into sql.

- Server Auth is set to "Mixed" (SQL and Win auth mode)

[image]

Comment: Is the server running ?

Comment: That would be a different error, @pippo1980 .

Comment: Check the SQL Server's logs to get the actual error. If you don't understand that error, include it in your question.

Comment: Also a `USER` isn't a `LOGIN` in SQL Server; they are 2 different (but normally related) objects. A `LOGIN` is an instance object, where as a `USER` is a database object.

Comment: Probably the Authentication mode is set to Windows only. You can check by executing `EXEC master.sys.xp_loginconfig 'login mode'`, as described at [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2191/how-to-check-sql-server-authentication-mode-using-t-sql-and-ssms/). In order to enable SQL Authentication as well, you can follow the proposed answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774827/cant-connect-to-localhost-on-sql-server-express-2012-2016 Old but already talking about mixed mode

Comment: Is the password correct ??

Comment: server is set to Mixed

Comment: What about the error, @tomsmithweb ? Give us that actual authentication error.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you set the authentication mode to mixed mode or not. If not then:

To enable mixed mode Authentication in Microsoft SQL Server please follow the steps below.

**To change security authentication mode to mixed mode**
In SQL Server Management Studio Object Explorer, right-click the server, and then click Properties.

On the Security page, under Server authentication, select SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode, and then click OK.

In the SQL Server Management Studio dialog box, click OK to acknowledge the requirement to restart SQL Server.

**To enable the sa login by using Management Studio**
In Object Explorer, expand Security, expand Logins, right-click sa, and then click Properties.

On the General page, create and confirm a new highly secure password for the sa login.

On the Status page, in the Login section, click Enabled, and then click OK.

Please look into below link:
[Solutions to Microsoft SQL Server Error 18456](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/troubleshooting-microsoft-sql-server-error-18456-login-failed-user/)

Comment: Consider improving your answer by adding some pointers on [how to check the authentication mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2191/how-to-check-sql-server-authentication-mode-using-t-sql-and-ssms/).

Comment: Please check at the last page of user create/edit module whether the user is disabled or not?